# Jquery addEventListener in Chrome with parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, google-chrome

A feature was developed in an application by clicking a hyperlink in a table, open a div below with a table, filtering contents, depending on the link.

The link was created dynamically in one jQuery function and had the following attributes:

```
$("#pending div#list").bind("data_loaded", function (event, records) {
    var tableBody = $("tbody", $(this));
    for (var index = 0; index < records.length; index++) {
        var rowHtml = '<tr id="' + rowid + '"><input type="hidden" name="' + rowid + '" id="' + rowid + '" value="1"/>' +
             '<td><a class="populate" id="' + rowid + '" onclick="javascript:clickHandler(' + rowid + ');">' + docid + '</a></td>' +
                     '</tr>';
        tableBody.append($(rowHtml));
    }
});
```

In Mozilla Firefox, it works perfectly fine. However in Chrome I cannot call the **clickHandler** function. 
From the information I find on Google, say Inline JavaScript will not be executed.

You can check here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy

But now comes my difficulty.

I changed my hyperlink to:

```
'<td><a class="populate" id="' + rowid + '" onclick="clickHandler(' + rowid + ');">' + docid + '</a></td>' +
```

And I created this jQuery:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
document.getElementById([parameter]).addEventListener('click', function () { clickHandler([parameter]); },false);
});
```

Can anyone explain how I can pass the parameter rowid for jQuery?

Thanks.

Regards.

Comment: Post more code, please. Where is this `td` being created? What's the code?

Comment: @Buzinas I edited the question. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your snippets imply you're using raw DOM manipulation in Javascript rather than JQuery (which is good! it's definitely faster) but since you mention JQuery, that's what I'll be suggesting.

Instead of your addEventListener call above, try

```
$('div#list').on('click', 'a.populate', function() {
  clickHandler($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

And then remove the 'onclick' attribute in the declarations of the anchor tags too.

This will add an event listener to all anchor tages with a class of 'populate' which will call clickHandler passing a string parameter consisting of that anchor tag's 'id'.

Comment: Thank you. I implemented their suggestion, however, still unable to call the clickHandler () function.I put a breakpoint in the code but does not go there.

Comment: Ah I see. The issue is that the elements aren't yet created when the event listeners are applied. I've edited my suggested 'on' snippet. Give that a lash!

Comment: You solved my problem! Thank you very much!!! Mainly by the alternative solution...

Comment: Great to hear! Just so you know, what is happening now is that all clicks on div#list are being captured by this 'on' click handler. If there are any child elements matching the second selector - a.populate - then the handling function is applied to each of them with the a.populate as the 'this' context.

Comment: Thanks. i was complicating something simple.